# Show function parameters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code

I have AWS MQTT client python project in Visual Code. I have installed AWSIoTPythonSDK library that allows to communicate with AWS server. But I cant get this library function parameters by presing `ctrl+shift+space`. What else I should do in order to see `AWSIoTPythonSDK` library function parameters in VS Code editor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get intellisense, the shortcuts should be **Ctrl+Space**.

By the way, the import codes should be `import AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib as AWSIoTPyMQTT`. If you just use `import AWSIoTPythonSDK`, there will be no prompt. Because `AWSIoTPythonSDK` is a package instead of a module, you need to import the module such as `AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib` in your problem to get intellisense.